# Unable to connect to cqlsh when encryption is enabled

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, cqlsh

I am trying to connect to cqlsh from remote (kuebctl command) when encryption is enabled, but I am unable to connect to cqlsh. anyone has a better way to connect?

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --restart=Never --rm --image cassandra cqlsh -- cqlsh cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local -u cassandra -p cassandra --ssl
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /root/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable.
pod "cqlsh" deleted
pod default/cqlsh terminated (Error)
```

Since I am connecting from remote, I cannot set the cqlshrc file.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify location of the certfile, and validate options via environment variables `SSL_CERTFILE` and `SSL_VALIDATE` correspondingly, but you'll need to mount certificate files anyway, so you can also mount corresponding `cqlshrc`...

See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/usingCqlshSslAndKerberos.html) for more details.

P.S. Also, if client validation is enabled, you'll need to provide client's key/certificate as well (options `userkey`, and `usercert` in the `cqlshrc`).

Answer (score -1):

Since I was using cassandra image to connect cql, I added the cqlshrc file in the cassandra image where cql is installed to get it working.